# How to prevent script loading in different domain

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have `<script src="bla"></script>` that can be loaded in several domains.
I want to know if there is a way to control the domains it will be loaded  on.
To clarify: My script is server-side rendered, so basically I can return empty string if the requested domain is invalid.

This is to prevent from other sites embedding my script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the referrer, but this is set by the user's web browser and is not 100% reliable.

I don't think there is a way to 100% detect which domain has embedded the script.

Comment: I can't think of one either. Checking the request headers is probably the best you can do. You can also check for things besides the referrer, like user-defined key/values.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just check the domain the request is coming on?

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.host.aspx, you can get it via HttpContext.Current.Request.

An example:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Host.Containts("fred.com")) {
   return; // Or you could do a Response.Write and Flush
}
```

You can also embed the script code into a closure and simply check at the beginning and return:

```
(function() {

  if (location.hostname == "....") return;

  ...more code here...

})();
```

Comment: JS is not an option, since it can be hacked quite easily.

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question. Check the Host property of the request .NET side - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.host.aspx, you can get the HttpWebRequest using HttpContext.Current.Request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same mechanism used to prevent hotlinking images-
mod_rewrite on apache, or an isapi filter on iis, for example

Either drop the request if it comes from another domain, or send a neutered script.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Content-Security-Policy` header would be a help in this case.
You can set this header using the `<meta>` tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self';">
```

You can learn about CSP in more detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).